# Are there instances of canonical Grobner bases (i.e. independent of term order)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, groebner-basis

I'm trying to define the computation of Grobner bases in some form of logic. In particular, this means that I should come up with a basis which is independent of the chosen order on terms/monomials.

My question is: are there known instances of ideals for which there is a set of generators such that Buchberger's algorithm outputs the same Grobner basis whatever the chosen term/monomial order?

I know it's quite a generic question, but let me know if you need more clarity wrt the background.

Comment: Yes, for example $\mathcal{B}=\{1\}$ as reduced Groebner basis, i.e., if the system of polynmial equations has no solution.

Comment: This is a good question. But degree orders and lexicographic orders usually lead to different Groebner bases.

Comment: Actually, almost always the results differ when choosing another monomial order. Exceptions are probably somewhat trivial, see above. Perhaps the question can be refined a bit, with some example?

Comment: I don't understand why "In particular, this means (...)"; it sounds dubious. Anyway, maybe interesting: When you have a Gröbner basis $G$ of a zero-dimensional ideal $I$, you get a finite basis of $R/I$ as a vector space by taking the monomials which are not divisible by leading monomials of $G$ (it follows from the division algorithm). When you know this dimension $d$, you can sometimes use it to prove that some other basis $G'$ is a Gröbner basis of $I$ with respect to some other monomial ordering (when the number of monomials not divisible by leading monomials of $G'$ equals $d$).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but to get something that doesn't depend on a monomial order, people often consider [Gröbner fans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_fan) which consider all monomial orders.